# How to convert formatted text to the plain text

Tags: python, data-conversion, utf

I have XML-files with data in such format:

```
<DataBlock>
  <Text>Name1</Text>
  <Text>Name2</Text>
  <Text>Name3</Text>
<DataBlock>
```

Data can be in different languages include Arabic, Chineese, Cirillic etc.
Also this data can contain the latin text in different gothic or handwriting UTF characters like this:

```
<Text></Text>
```

or

```
<Text></Text>
```

But I need to save them as a plain text like this:

```
<Text>ABB</Text> 
<Text>ZERO</Text>
```

As I understand it, the problem is that the text is now saved in long UTF codes:

[image: UTF codes]

But how can I convert it to simple latin symbols?

Comment: This is not a font problem. You are using here the unicode characters U+1D4D0 (MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL A) and U+1D4D1 (MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL B). That means that the problem is a correct problem that IMHO deserves a true answer, but the question was misleading.

Comment: `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', "")` => 'ZERO'` I disagree that this should be closed. It would be good to talk about how this works. You can normalize such text, which can be useful.

Comment: This is not an answer by itself but a hint: the mathematical alphanumeric symbols block is described [here](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf)

Comment: @Todd: your usage of NKFD here indeed deserves to be in an upvoted answer!

Comment: `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', "") => 'ABB'`  See if that works for you VsKc

Comment: @Todd: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!